# 90's/00's scifi movie with non-humanoids "good guys" fighting human-shaped "bad guys", including a bald one and someone with a green sword

Tags: story-identification, movie

I cannot recall much of the movie... I can vaguely remember that there were two groups of five(?) fighting each other. One group are good guys, and are not human-shaped; the other group are bad guys, and are human-shaped. A character in the movie uses a large ring (that has nodes that burns? cannot remember clearly) as a weapon. Of the bad guys one is bald, dressing in black and using a green saber.

The dialogue should be in English, so it might be an American movie, I guess...

I remember having seen the movie when I was really very young.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it? What time was it likely from?  Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. **You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title.**